# Swift4: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code. I tried to fix app crashing while textfield is empty. This method worked in my previous app.

While pressing touchCheck button with empty UITextField app is crashing with following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I didn't found any answer on stackoverflow that would work for me.

Also, I'm newbie at swift.

```
@IBOutlet weak var inField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var outLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func touchCheck(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey!", message: "Text field is empty. This may cause app crash. Please, enter a positive whole number to text field in order to get number checked!", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it", style: .default, handler: nil))

    var i = 2

    var isPrime = true

    let number = Int(inField.text!)

    if number == 1 {

        isPrime = true

    }

    if (inField.text?.isEmpty)! {

        self.present(alert, animated: true)

        outLabel.text = String("Text Field is empty!")

    } else if isPrime == true {

        outLabel.text = String("Number \(number ?? 1) is prime!")

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    } else  if isPrime == false {

        outLabel.text = String("Number \(number ?? 1) isn't prime!")

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    while i < number!  {  //error at this line

        if number! % i == 0 {

            isPrime = false

        }

        i += 1

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
guard let number = Int(inField.text!) else { return }
```

return an optional `int?`

that may be `nil` check it before usage

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the text field is empty before your declaration of `number`.

This will make `number` nil as it is right now when the field is empty

```
let number = Int(inField.text!)
```